# Comparing text data-type to string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to compare some characters of type 'text' to use in a condition. However, they are not matching or showing as true.

This is a postgresql db I'm working with... for example:

```
active_date timestamp := '2020-10-4';
day_of_week text := to_char(active_date, 'day');
```

Takes whatever date is entered, and stores into day_of_week, in this case, selecting day_of_week returns 'sunday' in the results.

However, when trying to use this in a condition,

```
(case
    when day_of_week = 'sunday' then 'True' else 'False' end
) as "true or false",
```

... always returns 'false'.

I'm guessing this is an issue caused by data types? What needs to happen to make the case evaluate as true? I tried `cast('sunday' as text)`

Still nothing

Comment: '2020-10-04' is a date.

Comment: @jarlh no kidding

Comment: `select rtrim(to_char(now(), 'day')) = 'sunday'; `

Comment: @Mike Organek, thank you- works.

Comment: Do you mean '2020-10-4' is valid timestamp? I'd expect an error.

Comment: From the docs:  `day full lower case day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)`  Here:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html  Probably for backwards-compatibility with stuff from the dark ages.

Comment: @jarl just the date is valid timestamp

Comment: Unrelated, but: your `case` expression can be simplified to `day_of_week = 'sunday' as "true or false"`

Answer (score 2):

By default `to_char()` will "align" values with spaces. If you don't want that, you can use the `FM` [modifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE)

```
to_char(active_date, 'FMday'))
```

> `FM` suppresses leading zeroes and trailing blanks that would otherwise be added to make the output of a pattern be fixed-width

---

In general, I would recommend not to use localized day names, as this can easily break your code if the SQL is run from a SQL client with a different locale. If you want to make that more robust, use `extract(dow from your_date_value)` with Sunday = 0 and Saturday = 6. Personally I prefer the ISO weekday which can be extracted using `isodow` where Monday = 1 and Sunday = 7

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
rtrim(to_char(active_date, 'day'))
```